# Form submits, but doesnt send form data when zipcode modal submits

Tags: jquery, forms, modal-dialog, submit

If you go to the provided link, you can see the form on the sidebar "Contact a Dealer". The idea is that the script will check to see if you have provided a zipcode that exists in one of the arrays.

If the zipcode is in either the array, it submits the data to the appropriate php link file. This feature works perfectly, and sends the data to my email.

If the zipcode is not in one of the arrays it will then trigger a modal window that allows the user to pick which dealer they want to send the form data to. This feature appears to work, but when I receive the data in my email, it sends an empty lead setup.
I have provided the script that I am using to submit within the modal, as well as the modal popup.

If anyone has any idea of what could fix this I would greatly appreciate it.

http://cdn.moranautoads.com/tmg/page/14-10-15_gthda-site/

Comment: You should rather be posting codes of form.php file. Since its the form.php file where the data is being posted and probably the code for mail is written.

Comment: The code in the form.php file works if you use one of the numbers in the arrays in the zipcode blank. The only time it sends a blank lead is when the dealer is chosen from the modal.

It seems inaccurate to suspect the php file of holding the issue, wouldn't you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two of the same variable responding to the clicks.
Had to separate the variables, and everything was in harmony.